# Parallel processing to fill list in python faster

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to speed up filling an array in python. I am wondering how I could use parallel processing for that. My code looks like this:

```
def get_value(val):
    ##THE RESPONSE OF THE REQUEST TAKES SOME TIME##
    return subprocess.check_output('curl -d "data='+i+'" http://my/url,com',shell=True)

N = 1000000
output = [0]*N

for i in range(N):
    output[i] = get_value(i)
```

How could I parallelize filling up the output array in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
def get_value(val):
    ##THE RESPONSE OF THE REQUEST TAKES SOME TIME##
    return subprocess.check_output('curl -d "data='+ str(val)+'" http://my/url,com',shell=True)

N = 1000000
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
outputs = pool.map(get_value, range(N))
pool.close()
```